# Would the system exhibit periodic motion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

A mass moving in one dimension has a potential energy given by :-
$$V(x)=\frac{k_1}{2}x^2+\frac{k_{2}}{x}$$
where $k_1$ and $k_2$ are positive constants and $x>0$.
Is this system exhibiting periodic motion?
any help appreciated.

Comment: See if  it is possible to have a local minimum for the potential.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a homework type question, I cannot go for a fully solved answer. But I can give you a hint.

You should try and use the relation $F=-\frac{dV}{dx}$ and you then get the force acting on the mass. Next, you get a relation between $F$ and $x$.

Your job is to use the differential form of force $(F = m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2})$ and solve the differential equation. If the solution function $f(x)$ satisfies the relation $f(x+T)=f(x)$ for some real value of $T$, it means it represents a periodic motion with period $T$. So the solution tells you your answer.

The calculation might seem hard but that is the most basic and standard procedure of solving such problems.

Comment: Also should mention that, whilst the presence of $\sin$ or $\cos$ is a sufficient condition for periodicity, it is not necessary.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance Yes your point is correct. There are other mathematical equations as well that imply periodicity.

Comment: To be precise: $f \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is periodic with period $T$ if $f(t + T) = f(t)$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$.